# PhalconPHP - How to clear all cookies

Tags: php, cookies, phalcon

How to clear all cookies with PhalconPHP?

I use this code without success:

```
$this->cookies->reset();
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are facing the same issues a few other people do too, there are [five directly related issues on the github](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/search?q=cookies&state=open&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93):

1. [Multiple Issues - Cookies - delete and update both](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2679)
2. [->cookies->set() doesn't work everytime](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/1800)
3. [Phalcon\Http\Cookie->delete() not working when session.cookie_domain is set](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2329)
4. [Fatal error while trying to get not encrypted cookie](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2372)
5. [Problem with setting cookie](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2267)

Some suggest sticking to native PHP cookie functions. See if the comments of any particular bug help with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```php
foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value)
{
    $cookie = $this->cookies->get($key);
    if ($cookie)
    {
        $cookie->delete();
    }
}
```